# Finding K for a cumulative distribution function.

Tags: random-variables

I have the following CDF for some fixed number $k$:
[image]

When $x$ is smaller than $1$ then $F(x) = 0$
When $x$ greater or equal to $1$ then $k - \frac{1}{⌊x⌋}$ applies.

However, I cannot figure out how to find $k$. I believe that $k$ cannot be larger than $1$ because if $x = 1$ then $2-\frac{1}{1} = 1$

Also, I am told that $FX(∞)=1$ is the key to find $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x \to \infty$ $[x]$ also tends to $\infty$ so $F(x) \to k-0=k$. But this must be $1$ for a CDF so the answer is $k=1$.

Comment: Would this scenario also be plausible: $F(1) = 1 - 1 = 0$ ?

Comment: No. You cannot say that $F(1)$  must be $0$ simply because $F(x)=0$ for $x<1$. CDF's may not  be continuous.

Comment: So in that case, where did the $0$ come from in here "$F(x)→k−0=k$"?

Comment: If $x >N$ then $n \leq x <n+1$ for some $n \geq N$. Hence $[x]=n \geq N$. This shows that $[x] \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. Hence $\frac 1 {[x]} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Ah yes, I understand now. Thank you

Comment: More simply $[x] >x-1$ always, so $[x] \to \infty$ as $ x \to \infty$.